# Go scan buffer hangs sometimes

Tags: go

I use the following code which works ok, however in some cases the process stuck and I dont see any output. example this code runs `npm install` or `mvn clean install` and most of the time it works well but sometimes it hangs and you dont get any output

```
func exec(stdout io.Reader, stderr io.Reader) (*bufio.Scanner, *bufio.Scanner) {
    scanout := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    scanerr := bufio.NewScanner(stderr)

    scanout.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
    for scanout.Scan() {
        fmt.Print(scanout.Text())
    }

    scanerr.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
    for scanerr.Scan() {
        fmt.Print(scanerr.Text())
    }
    return scanout, scanerr
}
```

Now if I change the order like following (err first and stdout second) I got some error output when the command hangs however I don't see the output online , when you run the command you see some output and when the finished you see all the rest . you can wait for the output for 2 min and more and you get long output at once at the end of the process.

How can I fix that I will be able to get the output online and also get some feedback when the process hangs?

```
func exec(stdout io.Reader, stderr io.Reader) (*bufio.Scanner, *bufio.Scanner) {
    scanout := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    scanerr := bufio.NewScanner(stderr)

    scanout.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
    for scanout.Scan() {
        fmt.Print(scanout.Text())
    }
    scanerr.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
    for scanerr.Scan() {
        fmt.Print(scanerr.Text())
    }


    }
    return scanout, scanerr
}
```

**update**

Should it be like this ?

```
func exec(stdout io.Reader, stderr io.Reader) (*bufio.Scanner, *bufio.Scanner) {

scanout := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
scanout.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
go func() {
    for scanout.Scan() {
        fmt.Print(scanout.Text())
     }
}()

go func() {
scanerr.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
        for scanerr.Scan() {
            fmt.Print(scanerr.Text())
        }
}()

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, you're reading from stdout of the process until the process ends. Then you read from the stderr. In the second case you read from err first, then out. You should be reading from both of them. Either use Cmd.CombinedOutput which will return both of them, or start two goroutines, one reading from stdin and one reading from stderr until the streams close.

```
scanout := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
scanout.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
go func() {
    for scanout.Scan() {
        fmt.Print(scanout.Text())
     }
}()
```

Comment: I've used combine output in the past and got some issues, than I switch to this option..., can you provide example for the second ?

Comment: Added a snippet for one of the streams

Comment: can you explain how it could help ?

Comment: also which one of them I should use first ?

Comment: By reading the streams from goroutines, you can read from both of them as the executing program produces output. If you read from stdin first, but the program produces output for stderr, then the program will hang if stderr buffer is full.

Comment: If you start two goroutines, it doesn't matter which you started first. They will read from the input/error streams concurrently.

Comment: ahh, a bit confused, should my function (the first option ) should remain the same and I should only add goroutine as your example or ??? can you please add the full picture ?

Comment: please see my update, should it be like the third option?

Comment: That's what I was describing.

Comment: Thanks, one question, shouldnt the outer-function have the same either ? I mean the function `exec` ?

Comment: You mean, exec should be in a separate goroutine? If that's what you're asking, then no.